# Source Code in iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, jekyll, liquid

For my website, I have little code files to download, such as python (.py) files. I have the `<a>` tags for the downloads, but would like to display the source code before downloading it. On hover, I can display an iframe, but am having trouble getting the code to display.

FYI: I am using github pages for everything, and the files are in the site repo.

Jekyll code for the DL list.

```
<ul class="dl-display">
  <!-- get the folder name that the index..html file is contained in -->
  {% assign path_array = page.path | split: '/' %}
  {% assign path_array_rev = path_array | reverse %}
  {% assign page_dir = path_array_rev[1] | prepend: '/'%}
    {% for item in site.static_files %}
        {% if item.path contains page_dir %}
            {% unless item.path contains 'index.html' %}
                {% assign split_path = item.path | split: '/' %}
                {% assign filename = split_path.last %}
                {% assign rev_split_path = split_path | reverse %}
                {% assign dirname = rev_split_path[1] %}
                {% unless item.path contains '.txt' %}
                    <li><a href="{{site.baseurl}}{{item.path}}" download>{{filename}} <iframe id="sourcetooltip" src='{{item.path}}'></iframe></a></li>
                {% endunless %}
                {% if item.path contains 'description.txt' %} 
                    <iframe src='{{item.path}}' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>
                {% endif %} 
            {% endunless %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Sorry if the code is a bit messy, as I am still pretty new to web development.

The code that displays the iframe when filename is `description` works perfectly and displays the text.

In the unless block, the file begins to download. Is there any way to display the .py files like the txt files are displayed instead of downloading them?

Sorry if I'm not clear, its my first time with HTML, CSS, JS, and whatever else is used in web development.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the iframe attribute `srcdoc`. It's value can be a whole page of HTML without investing time into a separate page.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<iframe id='ifrm1' name='ifrm1' srcdoc="
<style>
section {  
  padding:5px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6); 
}
code {
  font:400 12px/.6 Consolas;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  color: lime;
  padding:5px;
}
                                        </style>
<section>
<pre><code>
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&'

query = raw_input('What do you want to search for ? >> ')

query = urllib.urlencode( {'q' : query } )

response = urllib2.urlopen (url + query ).read()

data = json.loads ( response )

results = data [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]

for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
</code></pre>
</section>" width='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>
```